# How to Select Store Code from another table?

Tags: sql

I know this may be an easy question, but I've been stumped on this for the past hour and am not sure what terms to lookup that accurately describe what I am trying to do.

I have two tables. INVOICES and STORE_LIST. The SBS_STORE_LIST table has two columns, STORE_NO and STORE_NAME. An example STORE_NO=1 that mean STORE NAME is 
MAKKAH

In the INVOICES table, there's a column named STORE_NO same as SBS_STORE_LIST Value

How can I get the STORE_NAME=MAkkah in my query  ?

Here's my SELECT that I am stumped on:

```
select i.STORE_NO as INVCSTORENO,
       s.STORE_NO,
       s.STORE_CODE,
from INVOICES i
join SBS_STORE_LIST s
    on i.STORE_NO = s.STORE_NO
order by i.STORE_NO ACS
```

[INVOICES TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuea2.jpg)

[STORE_LIST TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqmVh.jpg)

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and desired output? not getting your requirement clearly.

Comment: kindly check the attached Pictures

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuea2.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqmVh.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.STORE_NO as INVCSTORENO,
       s.STORE_NO,
       s.STORE_CODE
       s.STORE_NAME,
from INVOICES i
join SBS_STORE_LIST s
    on i.STORE_NO = s.STORE_NO   
group by i.STORE_NO,s.STORE_NO,STORE_NAME,STORE_CODE
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i have 30 store_name not only "Makkah" , so i want to select invoices by store_name ?

Comment: for example : store_no(1)= store_name(Makkah)
store_no(2)= store_name(Jeddah)
store_no(3)= store_name(Ryiadh)
store_no(4)= store_name(Dammam)

Answer (score 0):

Please try it like this.

```
SELECT   i.STORE_NO as INVCSTORENO,
         s.STORE_NO,
         s.STORE_CODE,
         s.STORE_NAME
FROM     INVOICES i
JOIN     SBS_STORE_LIST s
ON       i.STORE_NO = s.STORE_NO
WHERE    STORE_NAME = 'MAkkah'
ORDER BY i.STORE_NO ASC
```